# Spring MVC based application is not landing to default success url while trying to access it using https url but working fine on http based url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, https, jboss

While running the spring mvc based application on http, it is working fine but once the application is moved to https based configuration, we are not able to get successful landing url page. The url which are non authenticated is working fine but the authenticated urls are not reachable even after providing correct login credentials.

Please help me with the missing configurations/issues to resolve this problem.

The application is deployed over Jboss server.

Below are the configurations done as part of application.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {      
    System.out.println("I am configure");

    http.csrf().disable();        


    // The pages does not require login
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/logout", "/resetPassword", "/forgotPassword", "/change-password", "/confirm-account", "/registerPage", "/registerwithemail", "/resources/**", "/logoutSuccessful", "/login/**").permitAll();

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/home").authenticated();

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").authenticated();

    // /userInfo page requires login as USER or ADMIN.
    // If no login, it will redirect to /login page.
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/userInfo").access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')");

    // For ADMIN only.
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')");

    // When the user has logged in as XX.
    // But access a page that requires role YY,
    // AccessDeniedException will throw.
    http.authorizeRequests().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");

    http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();

    // Config for Login Form
    http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin()//
            // Submit URL of login page.
            .loginPage("/login")//
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check") // Submit URL
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)// userInfo (Changed to) home
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")//
            .usernameParameter("username")//
            .passwordParameter("password")

            // For Remember-me
            .and().rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository()).tokenValiditySeconds(86400)


            .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/logoutSuccessful").invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "remember-me");   
}
```

if there is any channel security for http/https is required, please let me know about the configurations as I'm also traversing internally to different module using ip and port based http url.